# Show JSON Data property in for each loop of Vue.js Template

Tags: vue.js

**JSON Data**

```
{  
   "Data":[  
      {  
         "Country":"{\"CountryID\":1,\"Name\":\"United States\",\"Code\":\"US\"}",
         "Currency":"{\"CountryID\":1,\"Code\":\"USD\",\"Symbol\":\"$\"}"
      },
      {  
         "Country":"{\"CountryID\":1,\"Name\":\"United States\",\"Code\":\"US\"}",
         "Currency":"{\"CountryID\":1,\"Code\":\"USD\",\"Symbol\":\"$\"}"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Vue.js Code**

```
<table class="table table-bordered mb-0" v-if="MembershipRecords.length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Country</th>                            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="Record in Records">
            <td>{{ Record.Currency }}</td>
            <td>{{ Record.Country }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is how it looks on web page.

[image]

When I tried like this `Record.Country.Name` it displays nothing.

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have stringified data in the records column. Try this:

```
<tr v-for="Record in records">
  <td>{{ JSON.parse(Record.Currency).Code }}</td>
  <td>{{ JSON.parse(Record.Country).Name }}</td>
</tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/01ogLreg/